# Haystack indexes not all items

Tags: django, indexing, full-text-search, django-haystack, whoosh

I am using **django haystack** with **whoosh** for full-text search. There are nine different models to index, but when I search for indexed entries, it seems that none or not all of them get indexed for some models.

I try this at django shell, but I get 0 for some of the models when all nine models are indexed, whereas I get all of them if I index just some models.

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
SearchQuerySet().models(OneOfMyModels).count()
```

For example, I have Article model which is correctly indexed and all 1029 items are found if I rebuild index just for Article. But I get 0 results of Article items, when I rebuild index for all 9 my searchable models.

Versions of software that I am using:

- python 2.6
- django 1.3
- haystack 1.1
- whoosh 1.8

Are there any limitations in whoosh for the amount of indexed models or found items? What could cause such strange behavior? Have you experienced anything similar? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haystack search seems to work well when I downgrade whoosh to 1.3.3.

Comment: Haystack reported that the whoosh backend required 1.8.3 when I tried to pin to 1.3.3.   However, I had a similar problem and downgrading to 1.8.3 resolved it.  Thanks for the Tip!